# More efficient way to find all elements in a List

Tags: c#, .net, list

I got this code:

```
List<string> values = getValues();
Details detailsData = getDetails();

if (values[0].Equals(detailsData.Attr1))
    if (values[1].Equals(detailsData.Attr2))
        if (values[2].Equals(detailsData.Attr3))
            if (values[3].Equals(detailsData.Attr4))
                if (values[4].Equals(detailsData.Attr5))
                    return true;
```

`getValues()` returns a string list that i'm hoping (^^) is present on `Details` object.

Is there a more efficient or more "pretty" way to implement this code above?

**EDIT**

```
 class Details : MainDetails
{
    string Attr3{ get; set; }
    string Attr4{ get; set; }
    string Attr5{ get; set; }
}

 class MainDetails
{
    string Attr1{ get; set; }
    string Attr2{ get; set; }
}
```

Btw there could be some other objects like Details that extend MainDetails and require this validation.
So this is code is gonna be used multiple times.

Comment: Sounds like your AttrN properties should collectively be in an array instead. Then you can just loop it.

Comment: Will list always have count `5`? Are all the members `Attr1`, `Attr2` and so on of type `string`?

Comment: Could we have a look at the Details class ?

Comment: The thing is that Details is a subclass for MainDetails and i some attributes belong to the super class so it'll be difficult to put all AttrN in an array/list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple improvement:

```
if (values[0].Equals(detailsData.Attr1) &&
    values[1].Equals(detailsData.Attr2) &&
    values[2].Equals(detailsData.Attr3) &&
    values[3].Equals(detailsData.Attr4) &&
    values[4].Equals(detailsData.Attr5))
{
    return true;
}
```

If you're only doing this in *one* place, I wouldn't bother going any further. If you do the same thing in *several* places, you might consider setting up e.g. a function turning your `Details` into another `List<string>` and then compare them using e.g. `SequenceEquals`.

Edit: Although the more I consider it, the more it seems comparing a flat list of strings to one in a hierarchy of classes seems like a bad idea, here's an example of how you could do this in an extensible fashion. The base class "consumes" the top two values, then hands off to the derived class to check the remainder:

```
class MainDetails
{
    string Attr1 { get; set; }
    string Attr2 { get; set; }

    protected virtual bool Matches(IEnumerator<string> e)
    {
        // Check the first two items exist and match
        return
            e.MoveNext() && e.Current.Equals(Attr1) &&
            e.MoveNext() && e.Current.Equals(Attr2);
    }

    public bool Matches(IEnumerable<string> details)
    {
        using (var e = details.GetEnumerator())
        {
            // Check the details match. (Optionally check
            // that there are no "extra" details.)
            return Matches(e); // && !e.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}

class Details : MainDetails
{
    string Attr3 { get; set; }
    string Attr4 { get; set; }
    string Attr5 { get; set; }

    protected override bool Matches(IEnumerator<string> e)
    {
        // Check the MainDetails match, and the next three too.
        return base.Matches(e) &&
            e.MoveNext() && e.Current.Equals(Attr3) &&
            e.MoveNext() && e.Current.Equals(Attr4) &&
            e.MoveNext() && e.Current.Equals(Attr5);
    }
}

...

List<string> values = getValues();
Details detailsData = getDetails();

if (detailsData.Matches(values))
    return true;
```

I'm not sure of your exact use case but hopefully this migth give you some ideas.

Comment: Argh beat me by a few seconds. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change your properties to all be in an array, then you can at least write the code a bit more prettily... although this is *extremely* subjective!

```
List<string> values = getValues();
Details detailsData = getDetails();

if
(
    values[0].Equals(detailsData.Attr1) &&
    values[1].Equals(detailsData.Attr2) &&
    values[2].Equals(detailsData.Attr3) &&
    values[3].Equals(detailsData.Attr4) &&
    values[4].Equals(detailsData.Attr5)
)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a clean code where you use it you can put some indexers on your class.

```
    class Details : MainDetails
    {
        string Attr3 { get; set; }
        string Attr4 { get; set; }
        string Attr5 { get; set; }

        public override string this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (index)
                {
                    case 3:
                        return Attr3;
                    case 4:
                        return Attr4;
                    case 5:
                        return Attr5;
                }
                return base[index];
            }
        }
    }

    class MainDetails
    {
        string Attr1 { get; set; }
        string Attr2 { get; set; }

        public virtual string this[int index] 
        {
            get
            {
                switch (index)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return Attr1;
                    case 2:
                        return Attr2;
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This way you can use a for-loop to compare

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   if(values[i] != detailsdata[i+1])
      return false;
}
return true;
```

same could be achieved with just putting a Method on the class like GetAtttributValue(int i);

Answer (score 0):

There is no "clearer" way of doing this while your properties are named like that. You could use the reflection (to save 2 code lines), but this will hit perfomance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like

```
List<string> values = getValues();
Details detailsData = getDetails();

if (values.SequenceEqual(new[] { detailsData.Attr1, detailsData.Attr2, detailsData.Attr3, detailsData.Attr4, detailsData.Attr5, }))
    return true;
```

This uses the `SequenceEqual` extension method of LINQ, see [MSDN: `Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Rawlings answer. A function to turn the Details-object into a list, could look like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetDetailProperties(Details details) {
    yield return details.Attr1;
    yield return details.Attr2;
    yield return details.Attr3;
    yield return details.Attr4;
    yield return details.Attr5;
}
```

You can than use the SequenceEquals method to compare both lists.